# Showing a set is globally a graph

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I have a following problem:
Let $B^2$ be an open unit ball in $\mathbb R^2$ and
$$ S = \{(x, y, z) \in B^2 \times \mathbb R: \frac12(x^2 + y^2)z^3 + xyz^2 + z - 2 = 0\}$$

Show that $S$ is globally a graph of a $C^\infty(D)$ function $z = f(x, y)$.

I had no problem showing that it is true in a neighbourhood of every point using implicit function theorem, but how to show that this function is constructable globally? Does it require using something like the pasting lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show that for each $(x,y) \in B^2$ there exists a unique $z \in \mathbb R$ such that
$$\phi(z) =  \frac12(x^2 + y^2)z^3 + xyz^2 + z - 2 = 0 .\tag{1} $$
For $(x,y)= 0$ this is obvious. For $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ write $(x,y) = r(\cos t, \sin t)$ with $0 < r < 1$. We get
$$ \phi(z) = \frac12 r^2z^3 + \frac 12 \sin (2t)r^2z^2 + z - 2 \tag{2}.$$
Consider
$$\phi(z) = \frac32 r^2z^2 + \sin (2t)r^2z + 1 . \tag{3}$$
We claim that $f'(z)$ does not have a zero. This implies that $\phi'(z) > 0$ for all $z$. Hence $\phi$ is strictly increasing and $\phi$ has a single (real) zero.

The disriminant of the quadratic polynomial in $(3)$ is
$$\sin^2(2t)r^4 - 6r^2 \le r^4 - 6r^2 = r^2(r^2 - 6) < 1 \cdot (1-6) < 0$$
and this proves our claim.

As you mentioned in your question, the implicit function theorem allows to conclude that $f(x,y) =$ zero of $\phi$ is smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few thoughts.

The equation $1/2(x^2+y^2)z^3+xyz^2 + z-2 = 0$ defining $S$ is a polynomial equation in $z$, so finding an a function $f$ such that $z = f(x,y)$ comes down to solving the equation in $z$ for any given $x,y$. A cubic always at least one solution on $\mathbb R$ so we can always write $z = f(x,y)$ for some function $f$ (where $f$ maps x,y to a solution of the equation). Notice that this does not uniquely define a function $f$ as the equation could have several solutions. If you manage to prove that $1/2(x^2+y^2)z^3+xyz^2 + z-2 = 0$ always has a unique solution (if x,y are given) then you've found the map$f$ you're looking for. This shouldn't be too hard to show, indeed the map $z \mapsto 1/2(x^2+y^2)z^3+xyz^2 + z-2$ is strictly increasing (consider its derivative !).

I'm not sure how you can show that $f$ is smooth.

Comment: cool, thanks a lot

Comment: I think smoothness follows from the fact that it is locally smooth at every point